# Using MKStorekit with Rubymotion

Tags: ruby, rubymotion, cocoapods, mkstorekit

Where does the MKStoreKitConfiguration file need to go that it will be recognized by Rubymotion/ the MKStorekit Cocoapod?

Comment: +1. I've got the same issue when using MKStoreKit as a pod in Xcode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It must go in the resources folder.